# i use jquery navigation bar but it gives error $("#jqxnavigationbar").jqxNavigationBar is not a function in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am creating an application in mvc3 razor.i am using jqxnavigationbar to create navigationa panels. i added the required js and css files in the folders. below is my examle code in layout 
    
                  
                   Header 1 
                         
                           Content 1        
                                   
                                      Header 2
                                        
                                              Content 2        
                                                  
                                                          Header 3
                                                              
                                                                            Content 3

below is my javascript function in header portion

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Create jqxNavigationBar  
    $("#jqxnavigationbar").jqxNavigationBar({ width: 200, height: 200 });
    $("#jqxnavigationbar").bind('expandedItem', function (event) {
        var index = event.item + 1;

        alert("Expanded: Header " + index);

    });
});
```

but when i run the project it shown error

$("#jqxnavigationbar").jqxNavigationBar is not a function.  and navigation panels are not display in the browser.

what can i do to remove error and use jq navigation bar.

Comment: Have you referenced the required js and css file in your view/layout?

Comment: yes following files are reffered into layout <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>  
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jqxcore.js"></script> 
         <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jqxnavigationbar.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a mistake in my head section in layout page. After adding refference of required jqxnavigationbar js and css files I added the refference of jquery-1.4.2.min.js file.so it does not work for me. Now after removing those refference the final header code is below which works fine for me.

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jqx.energyblue.css")" type="text/css" />   
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jqxcore.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jqxnavigationbar.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jqxexpander.js"></script>  

     @*AUTOCOMPLETE JQUERY FILES AND CSS FIES*@

     <link href="/Content/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     @* <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @RenderSection("PageScripts",false)
```

put code for jqnavigation bar in javascript portion.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your script :

At the Top of your _Layout view ? 
Your error means that the jquery nav lib has not yet extended the jquery one.

Also look at the script window from your web browser debuging tool to check if you don't load multiple jquery-1.8.3* lib, you should only have one, the full ou minified one.

Comment: no i firstly add the refference of css and js files and then add the javascript vode in layout page.also i chek in the debuger there is single entry of jquery 1.8.3 lib and the error is show.